# python kill subprocess communicate on exit

Tags: python, subprocess, global, kill

Ive got a large script designed to run a task, one at a time. But I have an init script that uses start-stop-daemon to kill the script at any time we want. The script ends just fine, but the subprocess command runs untill it's finished. I suspect it could simply be a problem with how Im trying to do the global variables. Or that Im using .communicate with the subprocess. Anyway here's the relevant stuff from the code:

```
import subprocess
import os
import signal

pro = ''

def sigHandler( signum, frame ):
    global pro
    os.killpg( pro.pid, signal.SIGTERM )
    sys.exit()

def run(data):
    #I found an example using preexec_fn somewhere on stackoverflow. Cant
    #remember if they were using .communicate() or not
    global pro
    pro = subprocess.Popen( command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell = False, preexec_fn = os.setsid ).communicate()
    return( 1 )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal( signal.SIGTERM, sigHandler )
    while True:
        run( relevantData )
```

Comment: It seems the variable pro doesn't get data till the subprocess has completed. So when the sigterm runs while the subprocess is running, there's no pid data to kill. This is likely a feature of communicate(). I'd like to use wait() instead but I was running into buffer issues with output from the command.

Answer (score 0):

Friend helped me figure it out. As said in my comment, pro wasn't getting populated as the command ran. So I had to change my code to this:

```
pro = subprocess.Popen( command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell = False, preexec_fn = os.setsid )
pro.communicate()
```

and then it worked :)